# Checking cookie and session value

Tags: php, model-view-controller, multilingual, gettext

I am working on a multilingual website, and I have a problem now. When the $_GET['setlang'] is empty, language is set to en_US, even if I had ?setlang=pl opened before (which is working fine - language is changing)

```
empty($_GET['setlang']) ? $_GET['setlang'] = '' : $_GET['setlang'];
    switch ($_GET['setlang']) {
        case 'en':
            $lang = 'en_US';
            putenv('LC_ALL='.$lang);
            setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang.'.UTF8');
            setcookie('lang', $lang, time()+60*60*24*365);
            $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
            $_config['lang'] = $lang;
            break;

        case 'pl':
            $lang = 'pl_PL';
            putenv('LC_ALL='.$lang);
            setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang.'.UTF8');
            setcookie('lang', $lang, time()+60*60*24*365);
            $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
            $_config['lang'] = $lang;
            break;

        default:
            if((isset($_SESSION['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] ='en_US') || (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) && $_COOKIE['lang'] = 'en_US')){
                $lang = 'en_US';
                putenv('LC_ALL='.$lang);
                setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang.'.UTF8');
             }

            else{
                $lang = 'pl_PL';
                putenv('LC_ALL='.$lang);
                setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang.'.UTF8');
             }

            $_config['lang'] = $lang;
            break;
    }

    $my_name = 'default';

    bindtextdomain($my_name,'./locale');
    textdomain($my_name);
```

I can't get this script to change the language to pl_PL after I run ?setlang=pl action. When this get is empty, cookie value is changing to en_US ;/

How should I check it and avoid this problem?

Also I am working with MVC. Does this code seem to be right or should I put some code into model instead of controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if((isset($_SESSION['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] =='en_US') 
|| (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) && $_COOKIE['lang'] == 'en_US'))`

make comparisons with `==` not `=` this way you assign `'en_US'` whatever the `$_SESSION["lang"]` or `$_COOKIE["lang"]` is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started the session? You cannot set or query session variables if you have not.

Use session_start();

Answer (score 0):

```
$lang = "";

// Check if lang cookie is set
if(isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
// Cookie is not set
else
{
// Get language GET variable
    $set_lang = (empty($_GET['setlang'])) ? '' : $_GET['setlang'];

    switch($set_lang)
    {
        case 'en':
            $lang = "en_US";
        break;

        case 'pl':
            $lang = "pl_PL";
        break;

        default:
            $lang = "en_US";
        break;
    }

    // Set language cookie
    setcookie('lang', $lang, time()+60*60*24*365);
}

// Set locale
putenv('LC_ALL=' . $lang);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang . ".UTF8");
```

Comment: Thank you for the code :) I need to make some changes in order to make it work, because when sb wants to change language, while the cookie is set, it cannot be done in any way :)